discord.js - Making my bot add reactions to its own message
I want it so that after my bot has sent an embed it adds a checkmark reaction
This is my code
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
// Features Command
if (interaction.commandName === 'host') {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('New lobby, queue up in 1 minute!')
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setFooter({ text: 'discord.gg/XzNV6bxf7R' })
        .addFields(
            {
                name: 'VPN: Canada',
                value: '‎ ',
                inline: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'React with ✅ If you will be there',
                value: '‎ ',
                inline: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'Gamemode: Solo Showdown',
                value: '‎ ',
                inline: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'Pin:',
                value: '‎ ',
                inline: false,
            }
        )
        .setImage('bababababababababa');

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
}

});
nothing just help me write the code :)

After you've send your embed, you will need to fetch the replied message. Fetched message will return a Message Object needed to access message react method (MessageReaction).
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], fetchReply: true }).then(msg => msg.react('✅'));

